# Method which accepts both int[] and List<int>

Tags: c#, .net

Question: Write a single method declaration which can accept both `List<int>` and `int[]`

My answer involved something like this:

`void TestMethod(object param) // as object is the base class which can accept both int[] and List<int>`

But that was not the intended answer, she said so.

Any ideas how that method signature would be ?

Comment: Probably `void TestMethod(IEnumerable<int> param)`

Comment: I would have asked for more details: Do you need to use `Count` or array-like subscripting? If so, use `IList<T>`. Do you need to use any specific methods? If not, you can use `object`. Otherwise, use `IEnumerable<int>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`IList<int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6(v=vs.110).aspx) which both, `int[]` and `List<int>` implement:

```
void TestMethod(IList<int> ints)
```

On that way you can still use the indexer or the `Count` property( yes, an array has a `Count` property if you cast it to `IList<T>` or `ICollection<T>`). It's the greatest possible intersection between both types which allows fast access, using `for`-loops or other [supported methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ywykzh6(v=vs.110).aspx).

Note that some methods are not supported even if they can be called like [`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/63ywd54z(v=vs.110).aspx), you'll get a `NotSuportedException` at runtime("Collection was of a fixed size") if you use it with  an array.

Comment: For completeness, bear in mind that `IList<int>` will let you call `.Add()`, which will cause a runtime exception if you pass an `int[]` instead of a `List<int>`.

Comment: An array has a `Length` property. You can use `array.Count()`, but that's an extension method from LINQ.

Comment: @Corak: no, it also has a `Count` property via `IList<T>` --> `ICollection<T>`. You have to cast it before it's visible.

Comment: Okay, but you can't call it via `array.Count` you need to call it via `((ICollection<int>)a).Count`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: but you get a meaningful `NotSupportedException`. You don't need to use methods that are not supported if you want to provide a method that handles also arrays as input parameter.

Comment: @Corak: yes, or cast it to `IList`. In the above method you can use `Count`directly even if an array was passed. You also don't need to cast the array to `IList<int>` to be able to pass it to `TestMethod`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, I know you get a meaningful runtime exception - it's just that if you don't need the extra methods/properties (over IEnumerable<T>) you have lost compile-time safety, that's all. I just wanted people to be aware that using IList can allow that to happen.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I've already added it to my answer. I just wanted to keep as much list/array-"power" as possible and also restrict types to arrays and lists as desired (`IEnumerable<T>` includes much more types).

Answer (score 3):

This might be the right answer:

```
void TestMethod(IEnumerable<int> list)
```

Comment: How come? try this: `TestMethod(new int[]{1,2,3});`

Answer (score 2):

Your method could be like this

```
private void SomeMethod(IEnumerable<int> values)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
 private void TestMethod(dynamic param)
 {
     // Console.Write(param);

     foreach (var item in param)
     {
       Console.Write(item);
     }
}

TestMethod(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
TestMethod(new List<string>() { "x","y","y"});
```

Comment: @InvernoMuto: i have no idea what that means but it must be correct ;)

Comment: @InvernoMuto why don't you open vs and compile my code ?? and check the output ?

Answer (score 1):

How about using Generics:

```
public static void TestMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
   foreach(var item in collection)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(item);
   }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
int[] intArray = {1,2};
List<int> intList = new List<int>() { 1,2,3};
int[] intArray = {1,2};
List<int> intList = new List<int>() { 1,2,3};

TestMethod(intArray);
TestMethod(intList);

string[] stringArray =  { "a","b","c"}
List<string> stringList = new List<string>() { "x","y","y"};

TestMethod(stringArray);
TestMethod(stringList);
```

Now you can pass any type to it.